# Duplicate nodes in umbraco content tree

Tags: .net, umbraco

Currently i am working on a website, which is made in Umbraco cms. I am facing a problem of duplicate nodes creation. If i create a node and publish that node, then a new duplicate node gets created. This duplicate node is visible after i reload all nodes. It is a multilingual website. I am attaching an image for more clear explanation.

[image]

Comment: Which plugin/projects have you installed?

Comment: Haven't seen this before, you might have hooked into the Document.AfterPublish() or Document.BeforePublish() events somewhere and execute some code which causes this behavior. Or maybe some kind of installed package is malfunctioning.

Comment: @lucuma - i have installed folowing packages- Simple Starter Kit,
Goyaweb Multi-Language tools,
MultipleFileUpload,
ImageGen,
Image gallery
Google Maps for Umbraco,
Berto Ultimate Picker,
Axendo Ultimate Picker XPath,
uComponents

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have NOT setup multiple root nodes to handle multiple languages you should remove this file:   `AppCode/CopyDocumentToRelatedOnPublish.cs` from the project per the package instructions:

http://our.umbraco.org/projects/website-utilities/multi-language-tools

That package will create duplicate content nodes.

Comment: first of thanks for reply Lucuma. The thing is that I have used two root nodes, one for english and other for tukish.Initially i was getting related nodes on both side.But now i am not getting related node on second side.But that is not issue. I just want to prevent duplicacy of nodes at one side. so i wanted to know removing this class file may cause any error or not ?

Comment: I think the issue you have is specifically with that class file, but if you have a backup it shouldn't cause any harm as you can put it back.

Comment: thank you lucuma. I will try your solution..Hope it would work